# why would i get AttributeError when run grpc demo in python3.7.4

Tags: python-3.x, grpc-python

i installed lib:
googleapis-common-protos 1.6.0
grpcio                   1.22.0
grpcio-tools             1.22.0

i run a simple demo,then an exception occurs:

grpclib/grpcapi.py:1: in 
    import grpc
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/**init**.py:24: in 
    from grpc import _compression
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_compression.py:17: in 
    NoCompression = cygrpc.CompressionAlgorithm.none
E   AttributeError: module 'grpc._cython.cygrpc' has no attribute 'CompressionAlgorithm'

i try grpcio==1.21.1 grpcio-tools==1.21.1,it doesn't work.
but it works in python2.7. however i must run it in python 3.6+

here is the proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "io.grpc.examples.helloworld";
option java_outer_classname = "HelloWorldProto";
option objc_class_prefix = "HLW";

package demo;

service mrpc_service {
  rpc call (mrpc_request) returns (mrpc_reply) {}
}

message mrpc_request {
  string action = 1;
  string body = 2;
}

message mrpc_reply {
  string result = 1;
  string body = 2;
}
```

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The C extension of your `grpcio` package seems not installed correctly. Can you post your `pip` log for installation? Also, I would like to know what OS are you using?

This bug may need more context to debug. Can you consider file an issue to gRPC repo? https://github.com/grpc/grpc

Comment: it seems pytest causes this problem. it works by runing directly in python3 app.

Answer (score 0):

finally，i found the culprit;
i use pytest, and add pytest.ini like：

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    error
    ignore::UserWarning
```

remove, then it works. wtf!

Comment: note you should note your "error" and "ignore::UserWarning" are in the wrong order. filterwarnings directives are processed in order from top to bottom and your "ignore::UserWarning" will have no effect

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed now in pytest 5.3 or more https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/6314